# Finding and Creating Sub Menus Dynamically

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `ToolStripMenuItem` I need to check if it has a sub menu with a particular name, if it exists, add a new menu item to that sub menu, and if not, create the sub menu and add the item to the new sub menu.

```
ToolStripItemCollection menu = tsmi1.DropDownItems;
                for(int i = 0; i < menu.Count; i++) {
                    if(item.Category.Equals(menu[i].Text)) {
                        menu[i]. //need to add new menu item here....
                    }
                }
```

It may just be that I don't understand how the menu system actually works, but it appears I can't add an item to my menu object.

Comment: Have you tried menu.Insert()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your sub-menu a `ToolStripDropDownItem`?

The objects in `TooLStripItemCollection` are all of type `ToolStripItem`.  You may need to cast the item you find to the derived class, `ToolStripDropDownItem`.

That will give you access to its `DropDownItems` collection, which is another `ToolStripItemCollection` and has  `Add`, `AddRange`, and `Insert` methods.

I haven't worked with `ToolStripDropDownItem` myself, but that's the path I'd start on.

---

Edit by bwoogie:
Final code:

```
ToolStripMenuItem tsmi = new ToolStripMenuItem();
tsmi.Text = item.Name;
tsmi.Click += node_Click;

ToolStripItemCollection nodeMenu = nodesToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems;
for (int i = 0; i < nodeMenu.Count; i++) {
    if (item.Category.Equals(nodeMenu[i].Text)) {
        ((ToolStripMenuItem)nodeMenu[i]).DropDownItems.Add(tsmi);
    } else {
        ToolStripItem newtsi = nodeMenu.Add(item.Category);
        ((ToolStripMenuItem)newtsi).DropDownItems.Add(tsmi);
    }
}
```

Comment: Casting solved my problem! I edited your answer (waiting for peer review) with my final code to help people in the future.